# Studying on a work permit in Ireland

Tags: working-visas, students, ireland

I know the question is trivial, but I cant seem to find the answer to it online :/

If someone holds a Work permit to work in Ireland, are they also allowed to attend college as a part time student from a visa\permit perspective?

Answer (score 1):

The work visa alone has no prohibition on study. You may have to document your status in applying to a private college, and there are status criteria that have to be met in order to qualify for access to publicly-funded college education free of fees.

> [Third-level student fees and charges](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/education/third_level_education/fees_and_supports_for_third_level_education/fees.html)
>
> **Free fees**
>   To qualify for free fees, you must meet criteria with regard to:
>
> 1. Residence and
> 2. Nationality and immigration status and
> 3. Course requirements
>
> **Residence**
>   You must have been living in an EEA member state or Switzerland for at least 3 of the 5 years before starting your course. The members of the EEA (the European Economic Area) are the member states of the EU, along with Iceland, Norway and Liechtenstein.
>
> **Nationality and immigration**
>   You must also fulfil **one** of the following 6 criteria as regards nationality and immigration status in Ireland:
>
> You must:
>
> 1. Be a citizen of an EEA member state (see above) or Switzerland or
> 2. Have official refugee status or
> 3. Be a family member of a refugee and have been granted permission to live in the State or
> 4. Be a family member of an EU national and have permission to live in the State, with a stamp “4EUFAM” on your residence card or
> 5. Have been granted humanitarian leave to remain in the State or
> 6. Have been granted permission to remain in the State by the Minister for Justice and Equality, following a determination by the Minister not to make a deportation order under Section 3 of the Immigration Act 1999.